# What happens whenever there is a segfault in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, segmentation-fault

What are the steps that the Linux kernel does whenever the hardware raises segfault. Right now I know that through the IDT, the fault handler handles it, and somewhere along the road there is a message in the kern.log (dmesg) about the fault.

I am asking this question because I am developing an hypervisor, and whenever there is a segfault in user space (which should`nt crash the system), the system crashes (the crash happens only after the message in the kern.log). So if I could retrace what the kernel does whenever it encounters segfault it will help me a lot.

Comment: Does you hypervisor run on Linux, or is Linux the guest system? What exactly crashes?

Comment: @RalfFriedl it's a thin hypervisor, so it runs from Linux and make it the guest. The whole setup runs on VMware player, and the whole setup crashes. So somehow the segfault make the hypervisor enters a buggy state, that's why I want to understand what's the process of segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [arch/x86/kernel/idt.c:152](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/idt.c#L152) - `page_fault` is used in the IDT
2. [arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:1143](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L1143) - `page_fault` is defined as a wrapper function for `do_page_fault()`, implemented using the macro `idtentry`
3. [arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:847](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L847) - `idtentry` macro
4. [arch/x86/mm/fault.c:1562](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1562) - `do_page_fault()`

Once you reach `do_page_fault()`, you should see clickable links to navigate the rest of the code.  You can't do that for these first four steps, because Elixir doesn't understand the macro magic.  It also doesn't understand assembly.

If you need to look at any other traps, some of the other handler functions (`do_*`) are in turn defined by another macro, [x86/kernel/traps.c:281](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L281) `DO_ERROR()`.

The function that logs the segfault message is also in fault.c: [show_signal_msg()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L865).  A little freebie for you.  Elixir doesn't allow searching for strings in general, only identifiers.  GitHub also shut down their code search.  In any case it's hard to search for this message format string without actually downloading the source code, because `"%s%s[%d]: segfault at %lx ip %px sp %px error %lx"` does not contain a lot of specific words or phrases :-).

The above links are to specific line numbers of the v5.0 source code.  Using [Elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source), which I really like :-).

Comment: The question doesn't mention Elixir at all though?

Comment: @Will but I like it, and this answer says you need to click through the links anyway, which will tell you what Elixir is :-).  A bit of suspense for you.

Answer (score 1):

The user space is managed and run by the kernel, and thus if a kernel level segfault occur inside the user space it will affect the kernel.

Each system will behave differently according to the log setup, the kernel setup and whether it's using systemd or not (but dmesg is commonly the main debugging/log location)

In your particular situation if you know what process generate the segfault you use `strace` or `gdb appname` to debug the problematic process.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Step-by-step_debugging_guide this guide have more details about how to debug a segfault

Comment: As I staated the seg fault occurs at the user space, and I actually raise it on purpose. The thing I am trying to debug is how the default crashes the system through error in a different part of my code, aka the hypervisor. That's why I try to understand what Linux do when segfault .